# nvida drivers disapeared during night (poweroff/poweron) DKMS cannot be rebuild

Tags: debian, nvidia, dpkg, dkms

**my setup**

> inxi -SMG System:   Host: zaphod Kernel: 5.14.0-1-amd64 x86_64 bits:
> 64 Desktop: Xfce 4.16.0    Distro: Debian GNU/Linux bookworm/sid
> Machine:   Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: G750JX v: 1.0
> serial:     Mobo: ASUSTeK model: G750JX v: 1.0
> serial:     BIOS: American Megatrends v:
> G750JX.209 date: 11/18/2013  Graphics:   Device-1: NVIDIA GK106M
> [GeForce GTX 770M] driver: N/A    Device-2: Chicony USB2.0 HD UVC
> WebCam type: USB driver: uvcvideo    Display: x11 server: X.Org
> 1.20.11 driver: loaded: nouveau,vesa    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting resolution: 1024x768    OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.1 256
> bits) v: 4.5 Mesa 20.3.5

**crash context**

I use Debian testing *for some really needed reasons*

I need to use a High-resolution & secondary screen each day with 1920x1080.

Made an

> aptitude update && aptitude safe-upgrade

all was right at that point, so I finished my work a few hours & power off the system.

**here is the issue**

Power on at morning & got only 1st screen working, 2cd one remains dark.

Resolutions is stuck on 1024*768

Errors seem to indicate an issue on DKMS. Then I investigated around that. But without results.

But I just cannot reboot **until all procedures supposed to have been solved for anyone on many many many forums & google pages returns all without any exceptions** finish by an update of the initram & kernel **with deleting current ones**

and then rebooting , I just **cannot reboot any more** as far as all procedures **deletes** initram & kernel & **new ones cannot be build**.

here we go on each try whatever I do before *(clean, purge,

> install or reinstall nvidia drivers &/or legacy &/or proprietary &/or
> vesa/mesa)* finishes as :
>
> Loading new nvidia-current-470.57.02 DKMS files... Building for
> 5.14.0-1-amd64 Building initial module for 5.14.0-1-amd64 Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.14.0-1-amd64 (x86_64)
> Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/470.57.02/build/make.log for more
> information. dpkg: error processing package nvidia-kernel-dkms
> (--configure):  installed nvidia-kernel-dkms package post-installation
> script subprocess returned error exit status 10 dpkg: dependency
> problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver:  nvidia-driver
> depends on nvidia-kernel-dkms (= 470.57.02-2) |
> nvidia-kernel-470.57.02; however:   Package nvidia-kernel-dkms is not
> configured yet.   Package nvidia-kernel-470.57.02 is not installed.
> Package nvidia-kernel-dkms which provides nvidia-kernel-470.57.02 is
> not configured yet.
>
> dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver (--configure):
> dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Errors were encountered
> while processing:  nvidia-kernel-dkms  nvidia-driver needrestart is
> being skipped since dpkg has failed E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg
> returned an error code (1)

I 've just worked on that since about 10AM it is about 17:30PM  I just don't know how to solve that now

**ho, just a thing to avoid useless answers I Cannot REINSTALL sytem**

any Idea how to force build on ignore errors or anything similar or force build even on errors ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run into issues such as this, deleting old kernels and associated initramfs is the last thing you should do; instead, you can reboot into the previously-known working kernel. You’ve been bitten by [bug #994860](https://bugs.debian.org/994860): the NVIDIA graphics drivers currently in testing don’t build with kernel 5.14, and the latter just migrated to testing.

Why did this happen seemingly overnight? Until you powered off, your system was running a 5.10 kernel, which is the version that was in testing until two days ago. When you upgraded, [the newly-migrated 5.14 kernel](https://tracker.debian.org/news/1262058/linux-5146-2-migrated-to-testing/) was installed; and when you booted up again, that’s the kernel that was loaded. `dkms` noticed that the NVIDIA modules were missing, tried to build them, and failed because of the aforementioned bug. (It would have tried to build them during installation too.)

To fix the situation, assuming you no longer have the 5.10 kernel, you can install that to return to your previously-working configuration:

```
wget http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/l/linux-signed-amd64/linux-image-5.10.0-8-amd64_5.10.46-5_amd64.deb \
     http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/l/linux/linux-headers-5.10.0-8-amd64_5.10.46-5_amd64.deb \
     http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/l/linux/linux-headers-5.10.0-8-common_5.10.46-5_all.deb \
     http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/l/linux/linux-kbuild-5.10_5.10.46-5_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./linux*5.10_*deb
```

The NVIDIA modules should build fine for this kernel again, and you can then reboot and choose the 5.10 kernel from the boot menu. This won’t break anything else in your system, the 5.10 kernel is safe to use with Debian testing — in fact that’s what was in testing until September 28. (The above instructions won’t install *exactly* the same kernel, they’ll install an updated 5.10 kernel from Debian 11 — Debian testing doesn’t get security support.)

Alternatively, upgrade to the NVIDIA drivers currently in unstable, but be aware that [you might then run into issues with OpenCL](https://bugs.debian.org/994971) (if that’s important to you).